# Marklogic - Sorting a Map

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to count the most commonly used terms from a specific field of an executed search. I am then trying to sort the Map, but haven't had any success with order by or found any functions that would work.

Can anyone advise or point me to the docs that detail how to properly sort a map?

Here is a sample  map

```
<map:map xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <map:entry key="Orlando">
    <map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">2</map:value>
  </map:entry>
  <map:entry key="Christiantiy">
    <map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">3</map:value>
  </map:entry>
  <map:entry key="Fort Lauderdale">
    <map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">2</map:value>
  </map:entry>
  <map:entry key="Key West">
    <map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">3</map:value>
  </map:entry>
  <map:entry key="David Robinson">
    <map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">2</map:value>
  </map:entry>
  <map:entry key="Florida">
    <map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">8</map:value>
  </map:entry>
  <map:entry key="test">
    <map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">2</map:value>
  </map:entry>
</map:map>
```

Right now I am trying to a second loop through the map, (removing everything with count of 1), and trying to add an order by to it, with no luck.

```
let $_ :=
  for $tag in map:keys($temp)
  order by map:get($temp, $tag)
   return

      if (map:get($temp, $tag) = 1) then
        ()
      else
        let $_ := map:put($temp2, $tag, map:get($temp,$tag))
        return $_

return $temp2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

Here was my solution.

Instead of doing a search and trying to manually count the records, I use [`cts:values`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values), sorted by frequency. I make individual maps out of the key:values so that they do not lose order when added to a larger map.

Those individual maps are then added to a set, which can be cast to JSON.

```
let $current_epoch := xs:int(fn:substring(fn:string(xdmp:wallclock-to-timestamp(fn:current-dateTime())),0,11))

let $temp := map:map()

let $test := (
    for $tag in cts:values(cts:element-reference(xs:QName('value')),(),"frequency-order",cts:and-query((
        cts:json-property-range-query('creationdate', '<=', $current_epoch),
        cts:json-property-range-query('creationdate', '>=', $current_epoch - 172800)
        )))
    let $map := map:map()
    let $_ := map:put($map, $tag, cts:frequency($tag))
    return xdmp:to-json($map)
)
```

Comment: A `map:map` is a hash table, and its keys will always have an unpredictable order. The same officially applies to JSON too. Then again, you are actually returning a **sequence** of JSON objects here, and sequences do have order..